conditional menu with custom fields
currently i have, as custom field on buddypress registration, the option to register as User Type A or User Type B.
I want to show a menu for user type a and another menu for user type b.
How can i achieve that?

This can be done by registering different menu location for different users and then update location according to the User type which user selected during the registration time.
We need to add the given code to functions.php file of the theme.
In this code we are registering custom menus.
function custom_menus_registration() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
        'user_type_a_menu' => __('User Type Menu A'),
        'user_type_b_menu' => __('User Type Menu B')
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_menus_registration');


In this step we are updating User type meta according to User selection.
add_action( 'bp_core_signup_user', 'save_user_type_on_registration' );
function save_user_type_on_registration($user_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['user_type'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_type', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['user_type'] ) );
    }
}

Here we are using this code to conditionally display different menus based on the user type.
function custom_menu_based_on_user_type( $args ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user_id   = get_current_user_id();
        $user_type = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_type', true );

        if ( $user_type == 'User Type A' ) {
            $args['theme_location'] = 'user_type_a_menu';
        } elseif ( $user_type == 'User Type B' ) {
            $args['theme_location'] = 'user_type_b_menu';
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'custom_menu_based_on_user_type' );

